# How to set routes on a linux EC2

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-ec2, routes, ip

how do I set the below values in linux?

I'm able to set destination and gateway, but I can't find anything in the docs RE passing a flag for genmask, flags, metric, ref, use or Iface.

Can anyone provide the value to pass? I've been able to construct the below

```
sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.96.0 tun0
```

But I need the full command to add the below;

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.96.0    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. You might get a better response at: https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I'd suggest using the `ip route` command. It's a more modern way of managing routes on Linux.

e.g.,:
`sudo ip route add default via 192.168.96.0 dev eth0 metric 0`

Flags, Ref and Use are automatically determined and setting them manually makes little sense.